# Anybody know this geometric font, or a similar one?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a geometric typeface similar to the one used in the main portion of this logo.. would love to know if you recognise it or know a similar font.

I've tried WhatTheFont but... I mean, you see the picture... those font identification tool aren't going to work that well on this sort of image.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: There are some requirements for font identification questions, [please check it](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/2611) and [edit] your question to add more details. Also please try one of the font-identification websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a modified version of B-52

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/stockbucket/b-52/

[image]